# Add a 3mm margin to every side of an A5 document

Tags: paper-size

I am writing an A5-sized booklet (148x210mm). I used a template that I found online that uses the following options for document class:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,normalheadings,DIV=10,twoside=false]{scrbook}
```

Everything works beautifully and I am very happy.
Unfortunately my printing shop needs the document with an additional 3mm margin on every side which will be cut off in the end (so they want a 154x216mm document). Is there any simple way how I can add these 3mm without completely messing up my layout? I'd also be happy about useful suggestions outside of TeX, anything that goes beyond "Create a 154x216mm Photoshop file, paste each individual page in the middle of it, save it and put all the new, larger pages together in a single document"

Thank you very much!

-BW

Comment: Untested: `\usepackage[paperwidth=154mm,paperheight=216mm,showframe]{geometry}` (Showframe only for testing!)... perhaps, this requires the adjustment of margins anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tries to use the `geometry` package and its `layout` option. The layout is the logical `a5` area, shifted right by 3mm and down 3mm from top on a enlarged paper (152mm x 216mm).

The `showframe` and `showcrop` must be removed in the final production run.

Additionally, the package `crop` shows the crop marks, in this case the layout is treated as being centered on a `a4` paper format. This package should be commented out in a production run.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,normalheadings,DIV=10,twoside=false]{scrbook}


\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,layoutvoffset=3mm,layouthoffset=3mm,showframe=true,showcrop=true]{geometry}
\usepackage[center,a4,cam]{crop}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to add the `reset` option of `geometry` to keep the type area calculated by KOMA-Script.

Comment: @Tobi: I should do that, yes...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Awesome, it's perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Its been quite helpful, thank you very much. I will try and tweak it for my own needs. I am thiking of doing the same memoir with geometry

Comment: @Tobi Hmm, no matter what I do, with or without `reset`, adding the `geometry` package is destroying the page layout set up by the document class (here `sphinxmanual` with `report` as base class).

Comment: Hi, at the moment I have no idea wha this might happen. Maybe you should post a followup question and link to this answer …