# Add a 3mm margin to every side of an A4 document

Tags: paper-size, printing

I have created a document in LaTeX and the document is complete, but the printers have asked for a 3mm white board applied to the PDF, so the overall size is 6mm wider and taller than standard A4.

How would I do this?

I found a similar question but this is for A5 paper instead: [Add a 3mm margin to every side of an A5 document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198080/add-a-3mm-margin-to-every-side-of-an-a5-document)

````
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt, hidelinks, final]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\end{document}```
````

Comment: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80505/how-to-make-document-custom-page-dimensions) for possible duplicate.

Comment: @Niklas Much appreciated! That looks like something I could work with and achieve what I am after possibly.